# Failed to update "app_localizations.dart" from "arb" files for multilingual support in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJlat.png)

I already have these files, and today I wanted to update the text content inside them. So, I made changes to the ARB files. However, I found that I'm unable to retrieve the correct updated values. How should I handle this situation?

PS:  I upgraded intl once from version 0.17.0 to 0.18.0 before I try to update ""app_localizations.dart""